# XPath get texts inside a "might existed" tag

Tags: xpath

I have a HTML which contains some tags like below:

```
<div id="SNT">text1</div>
<div id="SNT">text2</div>
<div id="SNT"><span style='color: #EFFFFF'>text3</span></div>
<div id="SNT"><span style='color: #EFFFFF'>text4</span></div>
```

how can I get **all** the `text`s included in all `<div>` tags using XPath?

i.e.:

```
text1  
text2  
text3  
text4
```

Comment: What's the host language you use XPath with? I think you simply want to select the `div` elements and then take their string contents, how you do that depends on the host language and tree model, e.g. in the browser DOM you might access the `textContent` property (or `innerText` with older IE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//div[@id='SNT']//text()
```

This selects any text node that is a descendent of any `div` element in the XML document, that has an `id` attribute with string value the string `"SNT"`.

If you want to excclude the whitespace-only text nodes from this selection, use:

```
//div[@id='SNT']//text()[normalize-space()]
```

This is similar to the first XPath expression, but now each selected text node must have an additional predicate satisfied -- that the value of the **[`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space)** function upon its string contents is a non-empty string.

The value of the `normalize-space()` function is the empty string only when its argument is the empty string itself, or a string comprised of whitespace-only characters (space, NL, CR and Tab).

Comment: thanks, but this will return one additional empty strings for any `div` tag which includes an `span` I'm afraid.

Comment: @MBZ: I have updated this answer with another XPath expression that selects only non-whitespace-only text nodes.